# How do i query through mongoose with two independent queries dependent on a parent query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var EmpSchema = {_id:String, empName:String}
var ProjectSchema = {_id:String, projectName}
var reportSchema = {empId:String, projectId:String, comments:String}
//These are two many to many relations
```

Now when i query using mongoose the report Schema and store empId, empName, projectId, projectName, comments in an array for each report, i am getting inconsistencies.

```
var showDetails = []
reportModel.find({}, function(err, reps){
    var dispItem = {};
    reps.forEach(function(value, index, arr){

        //querying empColl
        empModel.findOne({value.empId},function(err, emp){
          dispItem["empName"] = emp.empName;
        });

        //querying projectColl
        projectModel.findOne({value.projectId},function(err, pro){
          dispItem["projectName"] = pro.projectName;
        });

        dispItem["comments"] = pro.comments;
        showDetails.push(dispItem);
    });
    res.end(showDetails);
});
```

Please Ignore any syntax errors. What i am trying to ask here is the two callbacks querying empColl and projectColl are independent and get fired sort of simultaneously. So data is not coming properly in showDetails. 
I tried nesting the two queries, that too didn't work (inconsistencies). Maybe promises is the way to go ???? (new to promises)

Comment: Why aren't you using Mongoose's support for reference [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to get the related data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting the calls should help with building each dispItem.

But you need some way to detect when they are all done before `res.end(showDetails);`
You can do this with a counter:

```
var showDetails = []
reportModel.find({}, function(err, reps){
    var numLeft = reps.length;
    reps.forEach(function(value, index, arr){

        //querying empColl
        empModel.findOne({_id : value.empId},function(err, emp){
            projectModel.findOne({_id : value.projectId},function(err, pro){
                showDetails.push({
                    empName     :  emp.empName,
                    projectName : pro.projectName,
                    comments    : pro.comments
                });
                if ( --$numLeft === 0 ) {
                    res.end(showDetails);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Or the promises way:

```
var repsPromises = [];
reportModel.find({}, function(err, reps){
    var repDefer = Q.defer();
    repsPromises.push(repDefer.promise);
    reps.forEach(function(value, index, arr){

        var empDefer = Q.defer();
        var proDefer = Q.defer();

        //querying empColl
        empModel.findOne({value.empId},function(err, emp){
            if ( err ) { empDefer.reject(err); }
            else       { empDefer.resolve(emp); }
        });

        //querying projectColl
        projectModel.findOne({value.projectId},function(err, pro){
            if ( err ) { proDefer.reject(err); }
            else       { proDefer.resolve(pro); }
        });

        Q.all([empDefer.promise, proDefer.promise])
        .then(
            function (emp, pro) {
                repDefer.resolve({
                    empName     : emp.empName,
                    projectName : pro.projectName,
                    comments    : pro.comments
                });
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log("The first error encountered was: "+err);
                repDefer.reject(err);
            }
        );
    });
});

Q.all(repsPromises)
.then(
    function () {
        res.end(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log("The first error encounter was: "+err);
    }
);
```

Comment: i was trying to match index with docs.length-1 in forEach loop... which itself is async... lesson learnt the hard way...